# Wordpress Image URl issue With Gatsby

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

Hello everyone i'm facing an issue with wordpress image ,actually i using gatsby for front end and wordpress for backend now in front side i only getting image url like this **/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/react-js-working.jpg** but i need the url full path with like **https://mysiteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/react-js-working.jpg** also when i upload image in wordpress then it store with this url, if any one have idea how to fix it then please tell me